# Map not opening without refreshing page once closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The website i am currently working on has a pop out div with a map of locations on it, my problem is once the pop up div has been closed i then have to refresh the page to open the div again 
It is running jquery - here is the code

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){

                    $('#view_map_of_stocklists_link').click(function() {

                        //$('#popupdiv').show('slow');
                        $("#popupdiv").css('visibility', 'visible');
                        $("#mappy").css('opacity', '1');



                    });

                    $('.closepopup').click(function() {

                        $('#popupdiv').hide('slow');

                    });


                });
            </script>
```

The styling

```
<style>
                #popupdiv 
                    {
                        position: absolute;
                        left: 50%;
                        top: 50%;
                        background-color: white;
                        z-index: 100;
                        height: 600px;
                        margin-top: -200px;
                        width: 960px;
                        margin-left: -500px;
                        padding: 20px;
                    }

                    #view_map_of_stocklists_link:hover {
                        cursor:pointer;
                    }

                    .closepopup {
                        margin-top: 60px;
                        border: 1px solid #ccc;
                        background-color: #000;
                        color: white;
                        cursor: pointer;
                    }

            </style>
```

and then the HTML itself

```
<div id="popupdiv" style="visibility:hidden;">
                            <center>
                                <iframe style="opacity:0;" id="mappy" src="http://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=zNedxWZ7lai0.krRxVqZZmyns" width="900" height="500"></iframe>
                                <div class="closepopup" style="width:200px">Close</div>
                            </center>
                        </div>

                        <h2 class="bold skin-font-color1">Our Beloved Stockists</h2>
                        <h5 class="skin-font-color1 p-wrapper"><!-- client txt -->  <div id="view_map_of_stocklists_link" class="skin-font-color4">
                          <h4>View map of   stockists</h4>
                    </div>
```

The website is http://www.tee-ze.co.uk/sosmoothies/

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're showing the popup map doesn't match the way you're hiding it.

You show it with:

```
$("#popupdiv").css('visibility', 'visible');
```

But you hide it with:

```
$('#popupdiv').hide('slow');
```

That fades it out but ultimately sets the CSS style `display: none` on the `#popupdiv` element.

When you try to show it again, it still has `display: none` on it. Setting the `visibility` doesn't affect the `display` style.

You need to make the hide and show match up. Either use the `visibility` style, or the `display` style, but use the same one for both hiding and showing (and jQuery's `.show()` method uses `display`).

For example, you might create the `<div>` with `display: none` instead of `visibility: hidden`, and then you can use jQuery's `.show()` and `.hide()` consistently.

Comment: so when popping up and hiding i need to set them both to a dispay instead of visibility? cheers

Comment: You could set both `display` and `visibility`, but personally I would pick one and use it only, probably `display` since that's what `.show()` and `.hide()` manipulate. In other words, don't use `visibility` at all, only `display` - in your HTML too. But first you should read up on the difference between `display` and `visibility` in CSS. Even though they are somewhat similar, they are two different things and you can't interchange them.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting 'visibility' to 'visible' instead of 'display' to 'block'. 
When jQuery .hide() is called it ultimately saves the previous display value and sets it to `display:none;` So you should be doing something like:

```
$('#view_map_of_stocklists_link').click(function() {
  $('#popupdiv').hide('slow');
});
```

Which I just realized you have commented out in your code. I wish I could leave a comment but I need more rep.

**Edit:** 
Sorry for complaining in may previous answer.

I just tried uncommenting the existing code and removing the visibilty stuff and that works just fine in your site. Try it.